# how can I create own style for GTK and enforce it in my application

Tags: c#, gtk

I would like to create a custom style for GTK and /use/ that in my application.

Even if I knew how to create the style, the application would use the style that is system default (or default choice of user who is running the application). Is it possible to override it, so that my application always use this my style (skin) created for it?

Comment: Be careful when you do this, though: users don't have default choices for nothing! Some people (for example, with sight problems) depend on their style in order to use an application, and they won't appreciate it if you force your style on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at [GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html). This is the class used in Gtk to parse and load css themes tweaked, you need to set a new provider for your application and make that provider load your custom theme.
The related functions are there, or closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the entire Mono Runtime (19 mb overhead) into your Application. Then there won't be any dependencies, your users won't even need to install .NET or MONO. 
Refer following link:
http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono

You can copy all the GTK# assemblies into your program directory. It isn't reccomended however because you may run into a lot of problems if the user has another version of the Gtk runtime installed.

You can integrate the GTK# installer with the Windows Installer of your Application.

You can use Deployment Management / Dependency Management Software, but this is expensive since all the good ones are propriety.

Also refer Following link:

http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono

Hope its helpful.